# In Android, JavaScript Interface Injection Vulnerability

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-security

My application received [Remediation for JavaScript Interface Injection Vulnerability] from Google PlayStore.

Webview control via javascript interface in non-https webpage.

This is my solution.

It is correct for this issue? or how to modify?

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

    if(request.getUrl().getHost().equals("mydomain.com")) {
        view.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "myview");
    } else {
        view.removeJavascriptInterface("myview");
    }
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
}
```

Comment: it is failed...

Answer (score 0):

I solved using https url. I installed on my site an ssl certificate.

Comment: I can not use https url for this. Because it is not my authority.. I already asked the client to add ssl, but rejected.