# How to address "Remediation for JavaScript Interface Injection Vulnerability"?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-security

Google has asked me to address https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9095419 in my Android app, which basically means not to use the JavaScript injection mechanism for a web page loaded via HTTP.

Not using this mechanism (option 1) doesn't work for me. Setting  android:usesCleartextTraffic to false also doesn't work, as the app uses non-HTTPS traffic elsewhere. So that leaves me with "you can ensure that any affected WebViews do not load any URLs with HTTP schemes via loadUrl" - which I'm happy to do, as my app only uses file:/// URLs to load content into the WebView, which should be fine security-wise. But how do I need to code the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method so that Google's checker recognizes that I'm using only file:/// URLs?

Note that the question is different from both [Remediation for JavaScript Interface Injection Vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53679624/remediation-for-javascript-interface-injection-vulnerability) (because I'm clear what is being asked) and [In Android, JavaScript Interface Injection Vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631536/in-android-javascript-interface-injection-vulnerability) (because I'm not using HTTP, but file:/// URLs).

Edit: Adding my shouldOverrideUrlLoading method. (This isn't the entire method, but the salient part of it.)

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView browser, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("file:///")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            browser.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, or is an entirely different kind of URI
        // (like tel:, geo: or mailto:), so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        act.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: My assumption is that `file:///` is handled the same as HTTP. Have you already tried to overwrite `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` with your own code? If you did, it may be worth adding to your question even if it doesn't work.

Comment: "Not using this mechanism (option 1) doesn't work for me" -- what is your `minSdkVersion`? There are other options (e.g., channels) for app<->JavaScript communication, but they are relatively new.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I'm targeting API 21, Android 5 and newer. "Other options" sounds interesting, even if they potentially only work for still newer versions; what would those be? https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview only mentions the JavascriptInterface approach.

Comment: @Filnor: I've added the gist of my shouldOverrideUrlLoading method.

Comment: Android 6.0 (API Level 23) added support for [HTML message channels](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/23/replacing-addjavascriptinterface-html-message-channels.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare: That was a very useful article about something that I had missed completely (if I knew how I would upvote the comment). Unfortunately, I am using file: URLs with assets, so I'm running into the same issues you did. But it reminded my of the evaluateJavascript method which I was able to use to solve my problem, even for Android 5. So while the original question remains unanswered, my problem is solved. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a way to use file:// URLs with assets in a way that satisfies Google code checker. While this would solve the issue, I'm still not clear how one might need to code it.

What I ended up doing -which solves my immediate problem- is to call a JavaScript method via the WebView.evaluateJavascript method. When called from within WebViewClient.onPageFinished the page has finished loading, so all elements are accessible. While not important for my case, this method can also return a value to the Java code. So while it's not a general replacement for a JavascriptInterface, it addresses some of its uses cases.